# OpenOrder occurs only for first open order interactive brokers

Tags: c#, events, interactive-brokers

I am trying to get all my open orders on TWS of Interactive Brokers, By using their API with .NET.

Like that:

```
IBClient _client = new IBClient();
_client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 7495, 0);    

if(_client.Connected) 
{    
        _client.RequestAllOpenOrders();
}

void _client_OpenOrder(object sender, OpenOrderEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Action " + e.Order.Action + " of " + e.Contract.Symbol + " in Status: " + e.OrderState.Status + "     order id:    " + e.OrderId);
}
```

But, the event seems to occurs only one time, for the first open order.

The description of RequestAllOpenOrders():(by IB)

> "Call this method to request the open orders that were placed from all
>   clients and also from TWS. Each open order will be fed back through
>   the openOrder() and orderStatus() functions on the EWrapper."

And the events occurs only for one open order.

why?

I am using Krs.Ats.IBNet.dll, v2.0.50727
thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I got it...
This all happend because throw Exception from event handler

```
    void _client_OrderStatus(object sender, OrderStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But Why do I  get now order id 0 for all open orders?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reqAllOpenOrders() I'm using reqOpenOrders(). It is worth trying.

You can check order.OrderId (3rd param of openOrder call), whether it contains the valid id.